# How to iterate in axios return the new percentage + array in every loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, functional-programming, logic

### **The problem**

I'm still getting used to functional programming (FP). Specially FP in React-native. The goals are:

- fetch different characters from the API through iteration
- each step returns the percentage completed plus its objects.
- the route and its headers may change. (e.g: instead of characters fetch planets instead)

### **The attempts**

Creating separated functions for each step was ok, the problem is how to 'connect' them and get the desired result (as described in 'The Problem' section). Every idea i attempted caused some type of coupling or repetition (of code)

**Requests**

```
function requestCharacters(start, token) {
  return axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/people/${start}/`,{
           headers: {
             Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
             ContentType: 'application/json',
           }
         })
}
```

---

```
function requestPlanets(start) {
  return axios.get(`https://swapi.dev/api/planets/${start}/`);
}
```

**Percentage**

```
const percentage = Math.round((start/finish)*100)
```

**Iteration of requests (using recursion)**

```
  async function loop(start, finish, callback) {
      if (start >= finish) {
        console.log("got inside if from loop");
        return;
      }
    
      await requestCharacters(1)
        .then((response) => {
          const percentage = Math.round(((start)/finish)*100)
          loop(start + 1, finish, callback({ percentage, pageContent: response.data });
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
    
loop(1, 3, console.log(percentage, pageContent));
```

**And then some function returning percentage plus object fechted**

```
loop(1, 3, PrintObjectsFromFetch)
```

How to solve this?

Thanks if you read to the end!

Comment: What's wrong with the function you've written? Also consider that you don't have to wait for each response 1 by 1, you could put all your requests in a Promise.all.

Comment: @codeLearnerrr the loop function need to be modified for passing data if you want to do recursion.

Comment: How would the route and its headers may change?

Comment: Hi @diedu, the change in the headers would happen if a 'Authorization: Bearer token' is added or removed. Just like in requestCharacters and requestPlanets. And the routes would change its url from characters to planets for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the non-refactored version. Hope it helps though**

```
import axios from "axios";

function mountAxiosRequest(url) {
  return axios.get(url);
}
const arrayOfPages = (total_pages, baseURL) =>
  Array.from({ length: total_pages }, (v, k) =>
    baseURL.replace("iterator", k + 1)
  );

const total_pages = 16;
const baseURL = "https://swapi.dev/api/people/iterator/";
const arrayOfRequests = (total_pages, baseURL, request) =>
  arrayOfPages(total_pages, baseURL).map((url) => request(url));

function PrintPercentageAndData(data) {
  console.log("from map percentage: ", data);
}

const mapResponses = (response, total) =>
  response.map((row, index) => {
    const indexFromOne = index + 1;
    const percentage = Math.round((indexFromOne / total) * 100);
    return { percentage, data: row };
  });

const promiseArray = (arrayOfRequests) => Promise.all(arrayOfRequests);

function GetPercentageAndData(callback, baseURL, request) {
  const total_pages = 10;
  const requestsArray = arrayOfRequests(total_pages, baseURL, request);
  const promissesArray = promiseArray(requestsArray);
  promissesArray
    .then((results) => {
      const result = PrintPercentageAndData(
        mapResponses(results, results.length)
      );
      if (result !== undefined) callback(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error("error from promissesArray : ", error));
}
GetPercentageAndData(
  PrintPercentageAndData,
  "https://swapi.dev/api/species/iterator/",
  mountAxiosRequest
);
```